# How do I enforce LF line endings in Jetbrains Rider 2018.1

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-10, jetbrains-ide, line-endings, rider

I'm frequently running into line ending issues with my JetBrains Rider 2018.1 installation under Windows 10. The IDE turns existing LF files into CRLF files once I edit them. I haven't yet found a way to configure it the way I want.

I would like to always only have LF in my files (for new ones and for edited ones). During a commit process, I don't want to get distracted by line ending changes.

My git is set to core.autocrlf=input. So it should behave neutral and use the as-is settings.

I know I can edit each file manually via the Line Ending switch button on the bottom right of the editor, but I feel that is quite cumbersome.

Comment: The answers here apply to your case: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205969644-How-to-Ensure-Always-LF-not-CRLF-on-Windows

Answer (score 38):

To change the default line ending for new files, Go to **File** → **Editor** →  **Settings** → **Code Style** and in the "Line Separator" dropdown select "Unix and OS X (\n)".

To change the line endings of existing files, select the files in the "Project" view panel, then go to **File** → **Line Separators** → **LF - Unix and OS X (\n)**. Make sure you don't break anything though - some file formats (eg .bat) only work with specific line endings.

Comment: I know. I tried that. I edit the file again and it switches back to CRLF again although I set it to LF before.

Comment: @Robert If you go to Code Style, there should be a "Scheme" dropdown at the top where you can select "Default (IDE)" or "Project". Perhaps one of them has line endings still set to CRLF and is overriding the other?

Comment: Just a warning for Unity3D users - setting the line endings for files can trigger a global asset reimport without warning, which can take ages and it just a pain.

Comment: I had this same issue and finally figured out that the `.editorconfig` file for the project had.

`end_of_line = crlf`

this was silently overrides rides settings.